# Android keep Nav Bar across Activities

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, navbar

(I'm not sure if it's the correct terminology but Navbar is referring to the slide-out menu that's common to android apps)

I'm new to Android development and had a question about keeping the same Navbar across screens. I noticed the default created layout (activity_main.xml by default) says to include the layout holding the content (content_main.xml by default).

My question is would it be easier to create new activities and load the Navbar into them, somehow switch out the content_main.xml when an option from the Navbar is selected, or is there another option I'm not considering?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the drawer in your main activity and create fragments, which will be the children of main activity. Have a frame layout and keep replacing the fragments in that layout.

This way you will get drawer in all the screens, no need to create a new activity unless there is no other option. And you can easily communicate between fragments via the parent activity.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main options to reuse the navigation drawer:

1. Make it part of a base activity and let all the activities that want to have the drawer extend this base activity. Make an abstract method in the base activity that returns the custom layout (R.layout.content_some_activity), that the sub-classes will provide at run-time. The base activity will replace the content frame with the provided layout.
2. Use just one activity and switch multiple fragments in the content frame.